# Использовать std::find_if или самописную функцию поиска? С++

Tags: c++, vector, итераторы, std

Есть класс, наследуемый от `std::vector`. В нем есть функция, которая ищет элемент и возвращает ссылку на найденный элемент. Именно ссылку, а не итератор. В данном случае лучше ли использовать внутри этой функции для поиска `find_if`, который возвращает итератор, или же написать свой алгоритм, который сразу бы возвращал ссылку? Вопрос в производительности. В обычных условиях лучше использовать решения из std, но будет ли сказываться на производительности тот факт, что `find_if` создает итератор, а потом его еще и разыменовать нужно, чтобы получить ссылку на элемент.
Стоит ли вообще беспокоиться о подобных вещах в оптимизации или это "экономия на байтах"?

Comment: а что Вы будете делать, если не нашли? бросать исключения? Но в Вашем случае, может задуматься о том, что бы данные держать отсортированными и применить бинарный поиск?

Comment: @KoVadim я думал об этом, когда рассматривал вариант со своим алгоритмом. Но, пожалуй, пока остановлюсь на find_if. Я не подумал про вариант, когда мы ничего не нашли, а бросать исключения мне не хочется, как и добавлять новый аргумент для контроля. Можно, конечно, как-нибудь применить опшионал, но, пожалуй, возвращать итератор было бы действительно правильнее

Comment: более того, этот итератор можно куда то дальше передать. Хороший компилятор может этот итератор почти до указателя довести. И все будет хорошо и быстренько.